# Arduino outputting 4.7V instead of 3.3V when using I2C communication/sensor?

Tags: arduino-mega, i2c, voltage

TOF050C-VL6180X Sensor was not responding, so I checked it with a multi-meter, and the VIN, GND solder pins on it read 4.7V. Double-checked Mega voltage, without anything connected, and it shows stable 3.6V. Connected a different ToF and it works perfectly, with a 3.6V on it.

So that proves that sensor is damaged (might've powered it with 5V at first), but I don't understand how is it taking more than the regulated 3.3V? If it was shorted, it would read 0V, and if something burnt, it would be open circuit and show ~3.3V, right? So how is it just getting 4.7V out of nowhere? Any ideas on what I'm not understanding here?

Thank you!

**EDIT:** More info, tried to isolate issue as much as I could

**1)** The non-working sensor shows 4.7V
[image: 1) The non-working sensor shows 4.7V on multi-meter]

**2)** The working sensor shows 3.4V and outputs distance to serial
[image: Working sensor shows 3.4V on multi-meter]

**3)** This is where it gets weird. I uploaded the simple blink sketch and now the working sensor shows 4.7V too

[image: Working sensor shows 4.7V on multi-meter]

**4)** So I tried **disconnecting the SDA/SCL**, while leaving power connected, with the blink sketch running, and it's back to 3.3V!

[image: Arduino outputs 3.3V to sensor]

**Tried the same steps with a different Mega, and **it always shows 3.3V, no matter the configuration!**

Now I'm very lost. So is the Arduino semi-damaged, with the I2C communication acting weird? Is it still safe to use with the project, if it *technically* works?

Comment: it is near impossible to guess correctly ... please provide a circuit diagram of the connections ... also provide a description of how you connected the voltmeter

Comment: @jsotola My project is a mess of wires and was hoping there are only so many reasons for such voltage incompatibility, but you're right, yall ain't clairvoyant. So I tried to isolate and detail the issue in the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Arduino Wire [enables the internal pullup resistor](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/1.8.5/libraries/Wire/src/utility/twi.c#L87-L89) on SDA and SDL. The internal pull-ups are specified at 20k to 50k. So you *are* providing 5V (or there about) to the sensor, though through a high resistance connection. So, the voltage isn't coming from nowhere.

It is not unlikely that there protection/clamp diodes in the sensor IC or on the sensor board that connect these signals forward through the diode to the IC's 3.3v connection.

So your SCL/SDA can be seen as very weakly (through roughly 35k) trying to backfeed your 3.3V regulator which is probably just blocking the current. If the sensor/board is using no current to speak of, either because it just doesn't normally or because it's dead, you would measure 5V minus a diode drop, or roughly the 4.7V you're seeing.

If you assume the internal resistors are both at 20K as a "worst" case scenario for a calculation, the current needed through one to drop 5v to 3.3v is 85uA. So with 170uA load on the board that would drop the 3.3V pin  connection back to its 3.3V level. About 170uA will flow through a 20k resistor with 3.3V across it. So if you want experiment take any resistor from about 470ohms all the way to just shy of 20k in parallel with your 3.3V / GND measurement and see if your 4.7V measurement doesn't drop right down to the normal 3.3V output.

Comment: Can't say I 100% understand the explanation, but tested it out with both a 560 and 18k resistor, and it really does go back to 3.3V, thanks! So the dead sensor pulls the 5V from I2C's pull-up resistor, because there's no load on the sensor...but then adding a load to 3.3V, it somehow ignores the 5V coming from I2C?

In the end, everything is fine and the board just isn't the highest "quality", with the mentioned worst case scenario of ~20K pull-up? Nothing to worry about and I can continue working with the board?

Comment: Also, since it's not exactly a specific sensor issue, is there a better title I could use? Like "Arduino outputting 4.7V instead of 3.3V when using I2C communication/sensor?". Can't find any posts about such an issue, so if someone's looking, they would realize that whatever is connected to 3.3V is just dead.

Comment: Interesting. Well, maybe I'll scrap that part of the answer. The principle part of it is that there _is_ a path to 5V. It's not being spontaneously generated.  Internal to the ATMega2560 there is effectively a pair of resistors between 20K and 50K in value that can be enabled that connect SCL and SDA to VCC (5V).  They normally are enabled when you use the Wire library.  The load is relevant here because it is through a resistance. You could also get 5V actively driving them HIGH but I haven't seen your code. I'll watch the question for details.

Comment: Oh, was there something unexpected about my answer? Here's how the [resistor testing](https://i.imgur.com/qfc1rF3.jpg) looked, if you're curious - breadboard powered by 3.3V pin, with resistor and sensor in parallel. The code is just the basic example from "Adafruit_VL6180X" library, and there is nothing driving pins HIGH in the example, but maybe deeper in the library.

And since you're not mentioning anything about the Arduino board acting weirdly, I'll take it as a green light that it's working within acceptable parameters.

Comment: I'm not going to explain the entire thinking process in the comments. But, in short my experience with using and helping with this kind of board and attaching this kind of thing has lead me to tentative assumption a board usually fine unless user reported using voltages above 5V, smoke, heat, smell, or light or unless it has been rather definitely proved not-fine. If I get bored may play around with the same sort of experiment with resisters and a comparable Arduino or otherwise remove the part of the answer that you have more or less shown to be unhelpful.